# How to use the SwingX JXTitledSeparator?

Tags: java, separator, swingx

I am trying to use the JXTitledSeparator from SwingX to create a separator with title, like this :

[image]

Here is the code i am currently using :

```
JXTitledSeparator xTitledSeparator1 = new JXTitledSeparator();
xTitledSeparator1.setTitle( "Separator Title" );
xTitledSeparator1.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
```

But i actually want is to move the separator title "Separator Title" to the left a bit, so it can appear like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
xTitledSeparator1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

or `SwingConstants.LEADING`. The `0` you are using stands for `SwingConstants.CENTER`.

If that doesn't work try [`setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT)`](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/weekly/week-20-2006-05-14/swingx/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTitledSeparator.html#setHorizontalTextPosition%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks, but this will move the title to the most left side, and won't do the effect as in the image above. I want the text to be moved a bit.

Comment: @Brad In this case I don't see another solution than taking the source of `JXTitledSeparator` and changing the method [`layoutSeparator()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.swinglabs.swingx/swingx-core/1.6.5/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTitledSeparator.java#JXTitledSeparator.layoutSeparator%28%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The solution i chose is using another JSeparator at the left side of the JXTitledSeparator which i use the SwingConstants.LEFT property for it, to give the result in the screenshot above.